# How to add page values to a PDF so that you can view the number of pages through windows explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, pdf

My question is based off of [this unanswered question](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/884524) on the Adobe forums.

**Background**:
The background behind why I want to do this is because I'm trying to plan the order & time needed to read some PDFs assigned by our teachers weekly.  I thought having the page number displayed in Windows Explorer would make it easier to plan/organize myself.

**Question**:
Why are the page values empty for the PDFs that I'm looking at through Windows Explorer?  Is it because the file was created without a page value?
[image]

**Additional**:
Also, is there a utility that will add the page value for a PDF file, and is there a way to batch add these values (recursively through a directory)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like neither Adobe nor Microsoft supplies a provider for the Windows Property System that provides that information for PDF files.

[Windows Property System: Property System Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)